# MarkLogic - Deploy tasks using gradle

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf, ml-gradle

- MarkLogic : 9.0-6.2
- Data Hub Version : 2.0.6

I created a task to monitor backups and placed the file at `\src\main\ml-config\tasks\taskmonitor.json`

I did a deploy (`gradle mlDeploy`), but how can I verify if the task has been created successfully?

I searched for *taskmonitor* in modules DB but could not find the task. Also, in admin console, I browsed to Groups-->Default-->Scheduled Tasks, but could not find any task there.

Answer (score 1):

`mlDeploy` should have deployed the tasks in the `/src/main/ml-config/tasks/` directory.

Have you tried running either `mlDeploy` or even just the [`mlDeployTasks`](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Task-reference#task-scheduled-tasks) task with the `-i` switch? Adding `-i` will give you more verbose output that could be helpful in diagnosing a problem (e.g. malformed JSON?).

Once deployed, Scheduled Tasks will be listed in the Admin UI where you were looking, under: `Groups-->Default-->Scheduled Tasks`

You can also obtain a list of the Scheduled Tasks via the [Management API REST endpoint](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/tasks): e.g. http://localhost:8002/manage/LATEST/tasks?format=html

Comment: Definitely use the "-i" flag as it will show you each directory that Gradle is looking at and which files it processes.